# How to change the number presented when dragging items

Tags: objective-c, drag, nsview, nscollectionview, nsdragginginfo

In `NSCollectionView` when you are dragging multiple items, there is a red circle with a number that indicates the number of dragged items.
I need to manipulate this number or at least hide it. Can anyone give me a clue how to do this?
Here is an example of the dragging in finder but I'm asking for an app of my own:
[image]

Comment: Your image shows dragging in the Finder. Are you asking about changing that behavior? Or are you asking about an app of your own design? If the latter, do you want to support dragging to other apps or only within your app?

Comment: @KenThomases I'm asking about an app of my own, and I want to support dragging to other apps. The image in the question is only for an example of that indicator. Will make it more clear in the question

Comment: @KenThomases Sorry, I want to support dragging only within my app

Comment: Just an idea: put the correct number of items on the pasteboard.